# Вывод количества дней в админке Django

Tags: django-admin

Добрый день есть модель в django с датой заезда и датой выезда, можно ли сделать так что бы при вводе даты выезда автоматически считалось количество дней. Если мои знания достаточны, то только можно сделать с помощью javascript? Или существует возможность вычисления дней, используя только django? Все делается в админке Django.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы хотите это делать сразу в форме то нужно переопределять форму и использовать js. Если же вам подойдёт вариант определения кол-ва дней после сохранения то можно обойтись только django

Comment: нет, мне как раз необходимо что бы в форме после ввода сразу считалось кол-во дней.